I am currently running a part of a series parallel 12 V LED strip current 200 mA from 12 V adapter. Can I add 3 LED single bulbs in parallel?
I made an infinity mirror and it has a 2 ft. part of an LED strip which is UV light it is a series parallel strip that draws 12 V. I have it powered by a 110 VAC to 12 V DC 700 mA adapter. Voltage under power is reading 12.5 V and has a current around 200 mA. My question is I have a void spot underneath stand of infinity mirror and I want to add three single red LED bulbs to illuminates the bottom.  Am I able to connect those three bulbs in a series circuit but in parallel with the LED strip so I'm not adding any extra power, unless it does add powder, and I'm already wrong?
3 @ 5mm RED LED - voltage at each bulbs 2.1 V (Tv 6.3). Resistance 285 Ω. Consumption  0.24 W (1/4 W resistor).
Strip LED - 12 V, 200 mA, consumption 2.4 W.
Totals of both circuits - current total 0.22 A (220 mA), consumption total 2.64 W.
Adapter limits - 12 V, 0.7 A (700 mA), now not sure if this is a calculation of what the adaptor can handle for watts which if it is it would be 8.4 W again not sure as I just jumped into all this 2 weeks ago the only thing I am 100% is the math at least for the inputs of the math. Thanks for to whoever takes the time read this. Also do like a spot on technical answer but please remember I'm only

Welcome! "draws 12 V" Current is drawn. 12 V is supplied or you can say a load expects or runs off it. I've tried to clear up your question a bit but I had to guess on ";24 W" to be 0.24 W given size of the LED. Please check and correct if needed.

Yes, you can add that additional 3-LED string in; the total current draw is well within your supply's limits. I would use a 300 ohm resistor as it's the next highest E24 value. Your power dissipation will be about 1/8W so a 1/4W resistor would be appropriate.
